# Attempting to place a Game Object at a particular position using an Animation Clip is not working as expected

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Game Object called "Slab" that I have attached an Animator and a Script Component to as shown below:

[image]

The Animator Component uses the "Slab" Animation Controller, which looks like below:

[image]

In the SlabIdle Animation Clip, I have set the same keyframes for the Transform Component at Frame 1 and Frame 24, because when the Animation Clip plays, I want the Slab Game Object to jump back to its current position.

[image]

Shown below is the script attached to the Slab Game Object

[image]

[image]

When I play the Scene, the Slab is at the position shown below:

[image]

When I hit the B key, the Slab Game Object jumps to the position of the Target Game Object as shown below
[image]

Now, when I hit the A key, I see that the SlabIdle Animation Clip plays but the Slab Game Object does not jump back to its original position:

[image]

but when I play the Animation Clip in the Unity Editor, the Slab Game Object jumps to its original position as below:
[image]
[image]

My Question is: Why doesn't the Slab Game Object jump to its original position when I play the Animation Clip programmatically?

Comment: why would it? it plays to the end of the animation specified and does nothing.

Comment: I thought it would since the position is captured in the keyframes, which I think is why it jumps back to its original position when I hit play in the Unity Editor.